# Radio button in my laravel 5.4 cannot be read by request

Tags: laravel

All of the other request in my view is included already in the request using
dd($request), but my radio button input is cannot be read by request.
attached here is my code

**View**

```
<form method="post" action="{{route('update-dependent')}}">
   <div class="form-group">
       {{csrf_field()}}
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="lname" value="{{$dependent->lname}}" class="form-control">
    </div>                                              

        <div class="form-group">
        {{-- conditional statement to check what geneder --}}
        <input type="hidden" name="gender" value="bading" class="form-control">
        <label>Male</label>     
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="form-control">
        <label>Female</label>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="form-control">
        </div>      

        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Relationship</label>
        <input type="text" name="relationship" value="{{$dependent->relationship}}" class="form-control">
        </div>  

        <div class="form-group">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
        </div>

</form>
```

**Controller**

```
   HMO::UpdateDependent($request); 

   return redirect()->route('edit', request('hmo_id'));
```

**Model**

```
public static function updateDependent($request)
{
    DB::table('hmos_detail')
    ->where('id', $request->get('dependent_id'))
    ->update([  'lname'         => $request->get('lname'),
                'gender'        => $request->get('gender'),
                'relationship'  => $request->get('relationship'),
    return true;
}
```

**result**

```
 array:2 [▼
      "_token" => "sP9FVEbL3pI5Yaf2jlSfDATNtOTSz2Rheb4bH9Ti"
      "lname" => "test"
      "relationship" => "WIFE"
    ]
```

Comment: All the radios have the same name property. Is that what you want? That might create issues with JS frameworks like jQuery

Comment: What do you see when you do dd($request()->all())?

Comment: It displays all request but it doesnt include the gender (I think because its a radio button)

Comment: yeah but it doesnt matter you have a hidden field with a value of `bading ` so you should get `$request()->get('gender') ` as  `bading `

Comment: Yes you are correct, but when I remove the hidden field, it doesnt read the radio buttons at all, ill edit my question and add the result of dd.

Comment: Let me ask you from where are you getting dependent_id from request? Show your route too

Comment: I already solve the problem by putting the radio button outside the modal, because Icheck and bootstrap doesnt work in that manner properly here is a issue that opens up my mind https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/issues/2294

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all if you want value of radio  then make sure you have proper validation in place.

If you don't know how to validate then have a look at following link 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/validation#validation-quickstart

Furthermore 
If you want some default value for radio button then make sure you  have a hidden field that will have default value is this case you dont need validation.

So the basic example would be

```
<input type="hidden" name="gender" value="bading" class="form-control">
```

The radio btn will always have bading as default weather its selected or not. But If you add

```
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" class="form-control">
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" class="form-control">
```

Then the hidden field is replaced with the selected value.

Comment: I think there is a bug, cause when I tried to use it in a simple view it works, but when I'm using it inside modal it doesnt read the radio button.

Comment: the hidden field should be in same form element if not it wont work.

Answer (score 0):

As @Sree mentioned, You need to give `gender` to the fillable.

```
protected $fillable = ['gender', ....];
```

> As from the documentation :
>
> Mass Assignment You may also use the create method to save a new model
>   in a single line. The inserted model instance will be returned to you
>   from the method. However, before doing so, you will need to specify
>   either a fillable or guarded attribute on the model, as all Eloquent
>   models protect against mass-assignment by default.

Comment: I'm still not yet into saving the data, I'm currently debugging why Gender RADIO button is cannot be read by Request $request

Comment: You mass assigning data to the DB, Laravel have that check that you have to define all things in the fillable. That's necessary, If you have still doubt then you should dig it a bit.

Answer (score -1):

It might be because you forgot to add `gender` in your Mass Assignment. In your model add,

```
protected $fillable = ['gender', ....];
```

Comment: How is fillable related to request? Dont think he is talking about persisting to database or so.

Comment: Yes what you say is correct. I just want to know how `$fillable` is related to `$request`. As far as I know I dont think  he's setting up `_token` as fillable but still getting the value.

Comment: I tried this, but this doesnt work, because upon submitting the form, the request itself doesnt contain the Gender, and I dont know why.